# Angular2 and ngrx/store application structure

Tags: angular, ngrx

Should the ngrx/store placed injected in a service or should it be injected into the component?

Does it make sense to decouple the component from the store use?

Comment: You should have a look at [this](http://bodiddlie.github.io/ng-2-toh-with-ngrx-suite/) and also [this](http://onehungrymind.com/build-better-angular-2-application-redux-ngrx/). Yes things should be splited.

Comment: The DI infrastructure already decouples the store and components. Some component interaction with the store is required for the dispatching of actions and the reading of state. Whether you require further abstraction/decoupling is a matter of opinion. Some guidance can be found in the [`ngrx/example-app`](https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) (which does not place the store in a service).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://blog.mgechev.com/2016/04/10/scalable-javascript-single-page-app-angular2-application-architecture/

This is the approach. 
Having a façade for both the store and the service.

Answer (score 1):

I would decouple Store from the presentation layer, but I would also decouple it from http services. [Smart components](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/smart-and-dumb-components-7ca2f9a7c7d0#.f9auxv6le) talk to an abstraction that exposes streams of state and has some functions which contains actions.

That particular abstraction also communicates with the rest of the application. Everything is completely loose coupled that way. I call that abstraction the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime, I wrote a blog article about this architectural question as well: 
http://blog.brecht.io/A-scalable-angular2-architecture/
I hope it's still relevant to your question =)

If you have any more questions, don't hesitate to poke me.